# Deploy changes in a folder through Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket

Please see the following scenario:

I have a couple of CSS files, JS files, and images in one of the folders of my branch in a bitbucket repository. Let's say:

1. Repository Name: WPTheme
2. Branch Name: DEV
3. Folder Name: Theme

I have an Azure Web app where my application resides. Now I want to automate the following process with Azure DevOps:

Whenever there is an update/commit made for the Theme folder. I want to deploy/replace this whole folder on my Azure web app Theme folder.

I want to achieve this using Azure DevOps.

I have done RnD but there seems no help regarding this particular scnerio. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever there is an update/commit made for the Theme folder.

For this requirement, you can set the trigger in Azure Pipeline.

Set the Branch and Path filder.

Here is an example:

[image]

> I want to deploy/replace this whole folder on my Azure web app Theme folder.

If you want to deploy to Azure App service again, you can use the [Azure App Service deploy task.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops)

If you only want to deploy the theme folder to replace the target folder.

You can use the [FTP upload task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops).

Here is an example:

```
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: $(build.sourcesdirectory)/theme'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftps://waws-prod-dm1-xxx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot'
    username: xx
    password: xx
    rootDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/theme'
    remoteDirectory: '/site/wwwroot/App_Data/Jobs/xxx'
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc: [Deploy your app to Azure App Service using FTP/S](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal)